# SUM only min values when various conditions are met. EXCEL and/or SMARTSHEET

Tags: excel, sum, logic, min, smartsheet-api

***TABLE 1***

| Initial Score | Actions | OC | Criticality | DT | Post Score | Current Score | Responsible | Completed | Due Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 252 | Expand to list actions |  |  |  | **105** | 140 |  |  |  |
|  | text | 6 | 42 | 6 | 252 |  | Jane | 100% | 10/25/20 |
|  | text | 5 | 35 | 4 | 140 |  | John | 100% | 10/30/20 |
|  | text | 5 | 35 | 3 | 105 |  | Sam |  | 01/25/21 |
| 324 | Expand to list actions |  |  |  | **135** | 216 |  |  |  |
|  | text | 6 | 54 | 4 | 216 |  | Cindy |  | 10/15/20 |
|  | text | 5 | 45 | 3 | 135 |  | Roger |  | 12/10/20 |
| 288 | Expand to list actions |  |  |  | **32** | 192 |  |  |  |
|  | text | 4 | 32 | 6 | 192 |  | Bill |  | 11/21/20 |
|  | text | 2 | 16 | 6 | 96 |  | Karen | 100% | 01/07/21 |
|  | text | 2 | 16 | 2 | 32 |  | Cindy |  | 02/28/21 |

NOTES:

In the "Post Score" Column, the cells in bold (105, 135, 32) are obtained using the MIN function, with the range being the cells right below.

*What I need*:

I want to NOT SUM the cells in the "Post Score" column where the "Due Date" Column is blank.

I Want to SUM the cells in the "Post Score" column only if the "Due Date" is before or equal to the respective "Date" (from table 2). BUT if there are two or more cells in the "Post Score" column that meet this criteria then I want to only SUM the MIN values for each group (by group I mean each set of actions underneath the "Expand to list actions".

I've tried the following:

=SUMIFS(Sum_range,Criteria_range1,Criteria1,Criteria_range2, criteria2)

=SUMIFS([Post Score]2:[Post Score]11,[Due Date]2:[Due Date]11,"<="&[Date]",[Due Date]2:[Due Date]11,"<>")

This returns the SUM of cells in column "Post Score" where "Due Date" cells are before or equal to the respective "Date" cell, AND where "Due Date" cell is not empty.

HOWEVER, I would like it to SUM only the MIN values in the Sum_range, where both criteria are met.

GOAL:

***TABLE 2***

| Date | What the score should be | Values that should be added from column "Post Score" | Logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Initial Score | 864 | 252+324+288 | SUM of "Initial Score" Column |
| 10/31/20 | 644 | 140+216+288 | SUM only if "Due Date" in table 1 is before or equal to "Date" in table 2. If there are 2 or more values that meet this condition only SUM the MIN value |
| 11/30/20 | 548 | 140+216+192 | SUM only if "Due Date" in table 1 is before or equal to "Date" in table 2. If there are 2 or more values that meet this condition only SUM the MIN value |
| 12/31/20 | 467 | 140+135+192 | SUM only if "Due Date" in table 1 is before or equal to "Date" in table 2. If there are 2 or more values that meet this condition only SUM the MIN value |
| 1/31/20 | 336 | 105+135+96 | SUM only if "Due Date" in table 1 is before or equal to "Date" in table 2. If there are 2 or more values that meet this condition only SUM the MIN value |
| 2/28/2021 | 272 | 105+135+32 | SUM only if "Due Date" in table 1 is before or equal to "Date" in table 2. If there are 2 or more values that meet this condition only SUM the MIN value |
| Final Score | 272 | 105+135+32 | SUM cells of column "Post Score" where "Due Date" is Blank |

Comment: I'm looking through this to see if I understand it. In table 2, for 10/31/20, you've got 140+216+288. Is this because there are _no_ dates before 10/31/20 in the last group, so you take the initial score instead (288)?

Comment: Yes exactly. For the first group I take 140 since this is the minimum score out of the two scores that are before 10/31/20. For the second group I take 216 since this is the only score that is before before 10/31/20. And for the last group I stay with the initial score since no score met the condition of being before 10/31/20.

Comment: I'm thinking it's not feasible to do it without a helper column (I've done a similar thing with a single formula in Google sheets but that's a bit more flexible)

Comment: I'd recommend that you [post this question](https://community.smartsheet.com/post/question) to the [Smartsheet Community forum](https://community.smartsheet.com). Stack Overflow is the place to ask programming-related questions (e.g., if you're using the API or an SDK to build an integration with Smartsheet), where as the Smartsheet Community forum is the place to ask product usage-related questions like this. There's a strong community of Smartsheet experts in the forum (customers and employees) who are well-suited to provide feedback on scenarios like the one you've described.

Comment: I've got a possible approach using Sortby - will post something tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Sortby:

```
=LET(initScore,FILTER(Table1[Initial Score],Table1[Initial Score]<>""),
filters,(Table1[Due Date]<=[@Date])*(Table1[Due Date]<>""),
groups,MATCH(ROW(Table1[Initial Score]),FILTER(ROW(Table1[Initial Score]),Table1[Initial Score]<>"")),
sortedScore,SORTBY(FILTER(Table1[Post Score],filters),FILTER(groups,filters),1,FILTER(Table1[Post Score],filters),1),
Seq,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Table1[Initial Score])),
filteredGroups, FILTER(groups,filters),
SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(sortedScore,MATCH(Seq,FILTER(groups,filters),0)),initScore)))
```

[image]

The screenshot shows the steps which are combined together in the LET formula taking 31/10/2020 as an example. In Table2, I have replaced Initial Score and Final Score in the date column by a month before the first date in Table1 and a month after the last date in Table1 respectively.